# Does iOS have a similar concept to sessions in Java or .NET?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, session

I would like to build a m-commerce application. I want to start with a login page.

Does iOS have something like the concept of sessions in Java and .NET?

Comment: Are you talking about a session id provided by a web server?  Because a Java & .NET client doesn't have session.

Answer (score 2):

There is no java like session in iphone. But you can use following method to save session data.

1. [Core Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) and either a SQL data
   repository or an XML repository.
   This is basically Apple's device
   database framework library available
   for all apps to use. It is not the
   easiest of options but it will allow
   you to store fairly large amounts of
   diverse data that will be available
   throughout your app code. In
   addition, the data is retained
   between app launches as long as you
   save it to the persistent data store
   before app shut down.
2. [Property lists](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html). Property lists are
   more lightweight than Core Data and
   you might find them easier to use.
   They allow storage and retrieval of
   basic key-value pairs into a
   persistent property list file. So,
   you also get the advantage of data
   retention between app launches as
   long as you store your data to the
   property list file before app shut
   down.
3. Store data to text files. I'm not
   sure if this has any advantage over
   property lists.
4. [User Defaults](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/). I'm not sure that you
   can so easily add new types of data
   during app usage. This is used more
   for providing a collection of
   default app settings and then
   allowing the user to personalize
   them during app usage.
5. In-memory [singleton](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) objects. This
   could be an option but, of course,
   once the app shuts down, all data
   goes away unless it's persisted into
   permanent data storage somehow.

This section is shamelessly copied from answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479358/save-session-data-in-iphone) thread.I just added some links..Credit goes there..